# custom request headers in rspec controller test being passed as rack.session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I tried following instructions on how to pass the custom headers but it's not working for me.  Here's what I'm calling in my respec test

```
post :create, {name:profile.name}, {'X-API-KEY' => 'somekey'}
```

From my controller I don't see it in the header as X-API-KEY but instead seems to be in request.headers["rack.session"]["X-API-KEY"]

How do I get it to not pass it as "rack.session"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been digging through the issue this morning as well. The problem comes from here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestProcess/process as the method signature looks like this `(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil, http_method = 'GET')`. This was quite unexpected to me and I'll keep looking though I'm not quite sure why it happens like this.

To get it working you could do

`before do
      request.headers['X-API-KEY'] = 'somekey'
    end`

This works, although not exactly what I wanted/expected from the `get` method.

Comment: Did you ever find out why the documented way doesn't seem to work? (Your solution does work for me)

Comment: this works but it would be nice to send the x-api-key header with the individual request so I don't have to create two entirely different `describe` blocks with their own `before` blocks in order to test different api keys...

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson According to https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/65 this is the way to do it. @sixty4bit you could just put this inside your `it` block right before you make the request, or write a method that does those two things for you, rather than in a before block.